# Java Best way to throw exception in a method

Tags: java, exception, methods, throw

I have created my own type of exception and want to implement it in a method. As of now I have written it in the following way, and it works.

```
public Worker remove (String firstName, String lastName, String number) throws NoSuchEmployeeException {
Worker w = null;
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
  if (list.get(i).getFirstName().compareTo(firstName) == 0 &&
      list.get(i).getLastName().compareTo(lastName) == 0 &&
      list.get(i).getNumber().compareTo(number) == 0) {
    w = list.get(i);
    list.remove(i);
  }
  else
    throw new NoSuchEmployeeException(/*"Employee could not be found"*/);
}
return w;
}
```

What I would like to know is if this is the best way to do it or if there is any other more appropriate/efficient/correct way of doing it. And also, do I need to declare the exception in the method header?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are just searching for an employee, then your method should return `null` or the `employee` object *(if found)*, but it shouldn't throw an exception.

Comment: Please use codereview.stackexchange.com for this type of question, not StackOverflow. This site is for problems when writing code.

Comment: I think you're exception looks fine.  To Habib's point, if not finding employees is normal flow, then you shouldn't throw exceptions.

Comment: Also, rather that a for loop with get(i) on the list to go through the list, I would use an iterator, then you can call iterator.remove() on it.

Comment: It's best practice to avoid implementing custom exceptions, unless they provide useful information for client code. In general, reuse existing exceptions.

Comment: Your logic is not correct. in the `for` loop it will check for only the **first** `Worker` in the list, if the first Worker is not the worker you are looking for then it will throw an exception.

Comment: What you could do is hold a static constant `Employee.NIL`. This is what you will return when the employee is non-existent. It can get rid of null checks and will enforce a basic OOP concept. This would be in place of an exception, which as @UncleIroh pointed out should be avoided if it is common.

Comment: I would recommend caution in adopting @Obicere's approach.  Returning a static constant means the rest of your program may run, instead of throwing an exception, if it doesn't check for `null`.  But is this a good thing?  Probably not, because the caller usually **should** be checking for this kind of result; and if it forgets to, this will lead to bugs that occur later and are harder to track down, rather than an exception that will make the problem obvious.  There are situations where this suggestion is appropriate, but in my experience it usually causes problems.

Comment: It was my understanding that throwing an exception is generally bad practice. It is better to catch the exception so the problem can be tracked. Can anyone confirm this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not going to comment on whether or not to use checked vs unchecked exceptions as that will provoke a monster debate.

If you create a checked exception, then yes it must be thrown in the method signature. If you create an unchecked e.g. extends from `RuntimeException` then you do not need to throw it in the method signature.

Checked exceptions are generally exceptions that are recoverable.
Unchecked exception are irrecoverable.

Comment: You should, be standard, only throw a `RuntimeException` is the program cannot continue after the exception. For example, a `NullPointerException` is runtime because the program does not know how to handle it, but failing to connect to a URL is not as large of a problem, since it can be circumvented - if the connection is needed though, then you can define that the program must halt on your own accord.

Answer (score 0):

In case you have some other information other than error message to be sent out along with the exception.

You will need to first create the Object of the Exception

set values you want to throw in the Exception

Or you can write your own constructors for the Exception which would take different values and exception message to create object to the Exception you wanna throw.

As such

```
throw new NoSuchEmployeeException(/*"Employee could not be found"*/);
```

is fine

Answer (score 0):

**1** Your code would be more efficient if you implemented [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) and the `compareTo` method in Worker as follows -

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Object obj) {
  // identity.
  if (obj == this) {
    return 0;
  } else if (obj instanceof Worker) {
    Worker w = (Worker) obj;
    if (w.getNumber().compareTo(number) != 0) {
      return w.getNumber().compareTo(number);
    } else if (w.getLastName().compareTo(lastName) != 0) {
      return w.getLastName().compareTo(lastName);
    }
    return w.getFirstName().compareTo(firstName);
  }
  return -1;
}
```

And then use the [SortedSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html) collection type (e.g. `TreeSet<Worker>`), especially the [remove](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#remove%28java.lang.Object%29) method.

**2** You should probably just return null. Throwing an `Exception` is certainly your choice, but (IMO) an unchecked `Exception` should be reserved for unrecoverable errors.